# ERROR: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm trying to insert data in to my Database, here's the command:

```
 public static bool InsertUser(string Date, string Day, string HourFrom, string HourTo, int HoursWorked, int Where)
    {
    string sql = string.Format("INSERT INTO Tablee (Date, Day, HourFrom, HourTo, HoursWorked, Where)VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}',{5},{6})", Date, Day, HourFrom, HourTo, HoursWorked, Where);

    return DAL.ExecuteNonQuery(sql) != 0;
}
```

Now I'm getting the error which I wrote in the topic and its from the line where I built my String Sql (the "INSERT INTO..."). Anyone have an idea how I might be able to fix it?

P.S. What is the purpose of the '{0}'.'{1}'..? I copied it from an old project I did and I do not remember why its in there and what it does.

Comment: Avoid creating a query by concatenating or formatting strings. Uses parameters instead.

Comment: Don't forget to comment your code; it may help avoid this problem ("P.S. Just cause...") in the future.

Comment: string.Format("format string", <format arguments>) will replace {N} pattern with N-th format argument, counting from 0. string.Format("{0} {1}!", "Hello", "world") will replace {0} to Hello and {1} to world returning "Hello world!" string as a result.

Answer (score 2):

You have **SEVEN** indexes listed (0-6) and only 6 arguments.

Remove the `{6}`.

Answer (score 2):

having this call:

```
string.Format("...{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}',{5},{6}...", parameters...);
```

you should provide 7 parameters, from 0 to 6, at the moment you are providing only 6:

```
Date, Day, HourFrom, HourTo, HoursWorked, Where
```

and this is the error.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of creative formatting illustrates your problem:

```
VALUES(
'{0}',   '{1}',   '{2}',      '{3}',    '{4}',         {5},      {6})"
Date,    Day,     HourFrom,   HourTo,   HoursWorked,   Where           <<whoops
```

Either remove the "6" or provide it with a value.